# Is there a way to override the delete_selected method in ModelAdmin but keep confirmation?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I have:

```
class Person(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['delete_selected']
    def delete_selected(modeladmin, request, queryset):
        # Show confirmation page.
        for obj in queryset:
            obj.custom_delete()
```

That comment I left there is where I'm struggling.  I still want to show the confirmation page before I perform my custom delete.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer**: you should override [**`delete_queryset`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.delete_queryset), since this encapsulates the real logic to remove the objects.

You should *not* override `delete_selected`. This action is [defined like [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/contrib/admin/actions.py#L13):

> ```
> def delete_selected(modeladmin, request, queryset):
>
>     # ...
>
>     # Populate deletable_objects, a data structure of all related objects that
>     # will also be deleted.
>     deletable_objects, model_count, perms_needed, protected = modeladmin.get_deleted_objects(queryset, request)
>
>     # The user has already confirmed the deletion.
>     # Do the deletion and return None to display the change list view again.
>     if request.POST.get('post') and not protected:
>         if perms_needed:
>             raise PermissionDenied
>         n = queryset.count()
>         if n:
>             for obj in queryset:
>                 obj_display = str(obj)
>                 modeladmin.log_deletion(request, obj, obj_display)
>             modeladmin.delete_queryset(request, queryset)
>             modeladmin.message_user(request, _("Successfully deleted %(count)d %(items)s.") % {
>                 "count": n, "items": model_ngettext(modeladmin.opts, n)
>             }, messages.SUCCESS)
>         # Return None to display the change list page again.
>         return None
>
>     # ...
>
>     context = {
>         # ...
>     }
>
>     request.current_app = modeladmin.admin_site.name
>
>     # Display the confirmation page
>     return TemplateResponse(request, modeladmin.delete_selected_confirmation_template or [
>         "admin/%s/%s/delete_selected_confirmation.html" % (app_label, opts.model_name),
>         "admin/%s/delete_selected_confirmation.html" % app_label,
>         "admin/delete_selected_confirmation.html"
>     ], context)
>
>
> delete_selected.allowed_permissions = ('delete',)
> delete_selected.short_description = gettext_lazy("Delete selected %(verbose_name_plural)s")
> ```

The key part here is that this action will perform the proper checks, but the deletion itself is done through a call:

> ```
>             modeladmin.delete_queryset(request, queryset)
> ```

So it is sufficient to override `delete_queryset` instead, with:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    actions = ['delete_selected']

    def delete_queryset(self, request, queryset):
        for obj in queryset:
            obj.custom_delete()
```

A `ModelAdmin` has a [standard implementation for `delete_queryset` [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1096):

> ```
> class ModelAdmin(BaseModelAdmin):
>
>     # ...
>
>     def delete_queryset(self, request, queryset):
>         """Given a queryset, delete it from the database."""
>         queryset.delete()
> ```

Comment: If delete_query set is modified to avoid deleting certain objects, then the message in delete_selected makes no sense anymore, because there will be less obj that were indeed deleted. Is there a way to modify the message?

Answer (score 5):

My requirement was a bit different. I had to intercept the delete_selected action and display error depending on the condition. This is what I did -

## In Model Admin

```
@admin.register(Model)
class ModelAdmin(model.Admin):
    ...
    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super().get_actions(request)        
        self.actions.append(delete_selected)
        self.actions.append(...otheractions)
        return actions
```

## Outside the Model admin

```
#Import goes to top of the file
from django.contrib.admin.actions import delete_selected as default_delete_selected

def delete_selected(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    response = HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())    
    #logic to validate
    for obj in queryset:
        if obj.name == 'test':
           messages.error(request,'error message')
           return response
    return default_delete_selected(modeladmin, request, queryset)
```

Comment: It helps me but if some one need it. Here are the imports that left: from django.contrib import messages and from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect