# How do I not show delete confirmation in Django admin unless conditions are met

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I overrode the `delete_queryset` method to add a condition before being able to delete a model.  It looks like this:

```
def delete_queryset(self, request, queryset):
    if condition_is_not_met:
        self.message_user(request, 'Error', level=messages.ERROR)
        return

    super().delete_queryset(request, queryset)
```

This DOES prevent the deletion but it shows that error message and below it says, `Successfully deleted 'x' objects` (Again, not deleted so success message should not be there).  I don't want to display that error message and what would be even better is if the confirmation page did not even show up if the condition is not met (This is a bonus though).  Any suggestions?

Comment: To anyone looking for a way to remove the "Successfully deleted" message, only way to do so seems to be to override the `delete_selected` action. A way to accomplish this seems to be: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59835462/1605873

Comment: A similar approach can also be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1471977/1605873

Answer (score 3):

Just override the `has_delete_permission` method on modeladmin, which will return True or False based on the condition.

```
def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    if condition_is_not_met:
        return False
    return True
```

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_delete_permission)

Comment: I guess my condition is sort of a “permission”.  The only issue I see is that it gives a weird generic message that doesn’t describe the permission if a delete is attempted.

Comment: what generic message do you get?