# How to remove default delete confirmation message from django admin on overriding delete queryset method?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

I want to override the default delete_queryset method in admin to prevent deleting last object.

```
    def delete_queryset(self, request, queryset):
        warehouses = self.model.objects.all()
        if warehouses.count() == 1:
            messages.error(request, "Can't delete last object")
            return False
        return super(WarehouseModelAdmin, self).delete_queryset(request, queryset)
```

The deletiion is working fine but along with the error message, "Successfully deleted 1 Warehouse.", this message is also being displayed.
How can I remove this success message?

Comment: To anyone looking for a way to remove the "Successfully deleted" message, only way to do so seems to be to override the `delete_selected` action. A way to accomplish this seems to be: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59835462/1605873

Comment: A similar approach can also be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1471977/1605873